# torchvision mnist RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

Tags: python, deep-learning, torch, mnist, torchvision

I have a pytorch and mnist error....
Why does this error occur?

**RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response**

```
    import torch
    import torchvision.datasets as dsets
    import torchvision.transforms as transforms
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import random

    training_epochs = 15
    batch_size = 100

    'mnist_train = dsets.MNIST(root='MNIST_data/',
                              train=True,
                              transform=transforms.ToTensor(),
                              download=True)'

    mnist_test = dsets.MNIST(root='MNIST_data/',
                             train=False,
                             transform=transforms.ToTensor(),
                             download=True)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

RemoteDisconnected                        Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\PSG\Desktop\Code\Python\pytorch\lab-07_2_mnist_introduction.py in 
     22                           train=True,
     23                           transform=transforms.ToTensor(),
---> 24                           download=True)
     25 
     26 mnist_test = dsets.MNIST(root='MNIST_data/',

RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: The code tried to download datasets but failed.  See the `download=True` parameter. You can try to download it manually and put the dataset to the predefined location.

Comment: Or just run the code again, until the dataset is downloaded, you or the server might have a flaky internet connnection.

Answer (score 0):

when I was run code:

```
import torch
model = torch.hub.load('mateuszbuda/brain-segmentation-pytorch', 'unet',
    in_channels=3, out_channels=1, init_features=32, pretrained=True)
```

I got similar errors:
"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response
"
There are multiple ways to solve it. Just be careful of some hints.

When I was running codes above, I got suggestions like :
"
change the command to {calling_fn}(..., trust_repo=False)
"
OR
"
You can also use load(..., trust_repo='check')
"
Then I add the parammeter to my code:
"

```
model = torch.hub.load('mateuszbuda/brain-segmentation-pytorch', 'unet',
        in_channels=3, out_channels=1, init_features=32, pretrained=True, trust_repo='check')
```

"
After that, the code run well.

Besides, you can get the URLs references to files which you are downloading from command line, like:
"
Downloading: "https://github.com/mateuszbuda/brain-segmentation-pytorch/zipball/master" to /home/xxx/.cache/torch/hub/master.zip
"

Thus, you can downlowd files manually.